# Basis of a set of a polynomial set of vectors based on a variable

Tags: linear-algebra

Determine all values of the constant a for which the set of vectors {*p<sub>1</sub>*, *p<sub>2</sub>*, *p<sub>3</sub>*} is a basis for *P<sub>2</sub>*(ℝ), where:

*p<sub>1</sub>*(x) = 1 + *a*x<sup>2</sup>,
*p<sub>2</sub>*(x) = 2x + 2x<sup>2</sup>,
*p<sub>3</sub>*(x) = 1 − x + 4x<sup>2</sup>.

My understanding of this problem is that it requires using the Wronskian to determine the effect of *a* on this set's linear independence or dependence in *P<sub>2</sub>*(ℝ). I figured that the most effective method to attain this would be to use elementary row operations to put the Wronskian determinant into row echelon form, and then calculating the determinant by multiplying the elements along the diagonal. I would then set that ≠ 0 to compute which values *a* must not be equal to in order for this set to be a basis of *P<sub>2</sub>*(ℝ). Is this an effective method for solving this problem, or is there a cleaner or more efficient/desireable method. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That’s certainly a viable way to approach this, but I think this problem is more easily solved by inspection. Observe that the constant terms of $p_1$ and $p_3$ are equal, so that in any linear combination of the three polynomials that vanish, their coefficients are additive inverses. Similarly, only $p_2$ and $p_3$ have a term in $x$, so the coefficient of $p_3$ must be twice that of $p_2$. W.l.o.g. we can take the coefficient of $p_2$ to be $1$, which produces $$-2(1+ax^2)+(2x+2x^2)+2(1-x+4x^2) = 2(a-5)x^2.$$ The values of $a$ for which this vanishes identically should be obvious.